# Calculating probability using the binomial distribution.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

The following problem fits quite nicely in the mold of Poisson distribution. However, for better understanding, I am trying to approximate probability using a binomial distribution.

> Denver, Colorado, is prone to severe hailstorms. Insurance agents claim that a homeowner in Denver can expect to replace his or her roof (due to hail damage) once every 10 years. What is the probability that in
>   12 years, a homeowner in Denver will need to replace the roof twice because of hail?

Specifically, I have trouble calculating `p` (the probability of success i.e. replacing roof twice).

Comment: Some details are missing.. What do you define as p- replacing the roof twice? Do you mean that the number of hailstorms after x years follows a binomial distribution?

Comment: @yes, `p` refers to  replacing the roof twice.

Comment: I think you should define $p$ as the probability of changing the roof once, and then calculate the probability of two successes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are interested in approximating this as a binomial you need to calculate the probability of success (defined as "changing the roof once in year"), you know that in a period of $10$ years you are expected to change the roof once.

Hence the probability of having to chance the roof once in a year is $p=\frac 1 {10}$.

So in order to calculate the probability of $2$ successes in $12$ trials  you can simply apply the formula.

$${12\choose 2}(0.10)^2(1-0.10)^{10}=0.23012...$$

Comment: `1 roof/ 10 years` => `0.1 roof / 1 year`. That's the logic you followed right?

Comment: Thats right, when approximating the poisson by a binomial you say that $np_n$ will converge to $\lambda$, in this case $10p$ must be taken to be $\lambda=1$

Comment: @thanks I think I got it